# NSPredicate to filter Custom objects based on its property from Nested structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

I am trying to use NSPredicate to filter all CustomObjects from structure shown below, and having value true for their property "isSelected".
I have an Nested structure like : `isSelectedProperty-Object-NSArray-NSDictionary-NSArray`.

```
[
  {
    "title": "ABC",
    "list": [
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = true,
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = true,
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = true
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "ABC",
    "list": [
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = false,
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = true,
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = true
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "ABC",
    "list": [
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = false,
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = true,
      <CustomObject>.isSelected = true
    ]
  }
]
```

From such Nested structure I need to filter all `CustomObject` having `isSelected = true` . So My Questions are,

- Is it possible using NSPredicate?
- Is Yes, then what will the predicate statement to filter this structure ?

Please provide some understanding so that we can understand how to actually deal with such structures.

*EDIT - Very Near to Solution*

After googling and help of answer of Muhammad Waqas, I succeed in filtering Array as below using

```
NSPredicate *aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"list.isSelected CONTAINS[c] %@",@true];
NSArray *aArray = [mutArrContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPredicate];
NSArray *UnWrapped = [aArray valueForKey:@"list"];



<__NSArrayI 0x7fc969cde360>(
<__NSArrayM 0x7fc969f54a10>(
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f7a590>,
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f8dee0>
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0x7fc969f736f0>(
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f68310>
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0x7fc969f737a0>(
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f70340>
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0x7fc969f87430>(
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f65170>
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0x7fc969f874d0>(
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f51690>
)

)
```

But Now I am struggling to filter this Objects into Single array like

```
(
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f7a590>,
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f8dee0>,
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f68310>,
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f70340>,
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f65170>,
<ContactData: 0x7fc969f51690>
)
```

Answer (score 5):

YES you can filter custom objects using NSPredicate like this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate    predicateWithFormat:@"ANY list.isSelected = %@",@true];
NSArray *filteredArry=[[json filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] copy];
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: This is crashing.
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ContactData 0x7ff74ea48320> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ContactData.' `

Here ContactData is Subclass of NSObject and has reffered as CustomObject in MyQuestion.

Comment: Using `NSPredicate *aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"list.isSelected CONTAINS[c] %@",@true];` I am able to get filtered Array but its in MultiDimensional, but i am trying to get it in Single Array. getting my point ?

Comment: for getting a single dimension array you have to iterate through each element and add it into your new array ....you can't achieve this using nspredicate